# Check if dataframe satisfies database table column definitions

Tags: python, pandas, database, sqlalchemy

Is there a way to check if pandas dataframe satisfies definitions of table comlumns in a database? I want to do this inspection before using pd.to_sql() funcion in order to avoid errors and exceptions.

Say for example that a table column is of VARCHAR(50) type, but one record in df has length of more than 50 and I want to catch this before pd.to_sql() execution. VARCHAR might actually one of the easier ones since it's just a string but my tables contain dates, numbers, etc.

I am able to obtain definitions using:

```
from sqlalchemy import inspect
inspection = inspect(engine)
definitions = inspection.get_columns('table')

# definitions contains a list of dicts like:
# [{'name': 'col_name', 'type': VARCHAR(length=255), 'default': None, 'nullable': True}, {...}, {...}]
```

but I am stuck at how to actually compare all values with definitions.

I am running multiple ETLs and doing this in a easy way is would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Pydantic](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/models/) models to parse and [validate](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/validators/) your data before inserting in the database.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).